# Bash script to forward ports

Tags: linux, bash, shell, portforwarding

I searched a lot on google but didn't find any answer to my question.

I want to forward 8080 port of my router to 192.168.1.7:5555. I have tried to setup this through GUI of my router but it is not working.
Making a bash script and putting it in router can make it possible.

Please help me, If anyone knows how to port forward using shell scripting.

**Edit**

I have OpenWRT installed in my router.
I am unable to update my router. Below is the error which i get whenever i run "opkg update"

```
Downloading http://downloads.openwrt.org/backfire/10.03.1/ath79/packages/Packages.gz.
wget: server returned error: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Collected errors:
 * opkg_download: Failed to download http://downloads.openwrt.org/backfire/10.03.1/ath79/packages/Packages.gz, wget returned 1
```

So, I will not be able to install any package in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [miniupnp](http://miniupnp.free.fr/).

Then, from port 8080 to 5555, run this command.

> upnpc -a 192.168.1.7 5555 8080 TCP

Comment: my router has OpenWRT installed, which is installed by Binatone Telecom. Is this software available for openwrt

Answer (score 0):

When you don't mind Perl, you can use the solution I found on http://www.catonmat.net/blog/perl-tcp-proxy/ :

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use IO::Socket::INET;
use IO::Select;

my @allowed_ips = ('all', '10.10.10.5');
my $ioset = IO::Select->new;
my %socket_map;

my $debug = 1;

sub new_conn {
    my ($host, $port) = @_;
    return IO::Socket::INET->new(
        PeerAddr => $host,
        PeerPort => $port
    ) || die "Unable to connect to $host:$port: $!";
}

sub new_server {
    my ($host, $port) = @_;
    my $server = IO::Socket::INET->new(
        LocalAddr => $host,
        LocalPort => $port,
        ReuseAddr => 1,
        Listen    => 100
    ) || die "Unable to listen on $host:$port: $!";
}

sub new_connection {
    my $server = shift;
    my $remote_host = shift;
    my $remote_port = shift;

    my $client = $server->accept;
    my $client_ip = client_ip($client);

    unless (client_allowed($client)) {
        print "Connection from $client_ip denied.\n" if $debug;
        $client->close;
        return;
    }
    print "Connection from $client_ip accepted.\n" if $debug;

    my $remote = new_conn($remote_host, $remote_port);
    $ioset->add($client);
    $ioset->add($remote);

    $socket_map{$client} = $remote;
    $socket_map{$remote} = $client;
}

sub close_connection {
    my $client = shift;
    my $client_ip = client_ip($client);
    my $remote = $socket_map{$client};

    $ioset->remove($client);
    $ioset->remove($remote);

    delete $socket_map{$client};
    delete $socket_map{$remote};

    $client->close;
    $remote->close;

    print "Connection from $client_ip closed.\n" if $debug;
}

sub client_ip {
    my $client = shift;
    return inet_ntoa($client->sockaddr);
}

sub client_allowed {
    my $client = shift;
    my $client_ip = client_ip($client);
    return grep { $_ eq $client_ip || $_ eq 'all' } @allowed_ips;
}

die "Usage: $0 <local port> <remote_host:remote_port>" unless @ARGV == 2;

my $local_port = shift;
my ($remote_host, $remote_port) = split ':', shift();


print "Starting a server on 0.0.0.0:$local_port\n";
my $server = new_server('0.0.0.0', $local_port);
$ioset->add($server);

while (1) {
    for my $socket ($ioset->can_read) {
        if ($socket == $server) {
            new_connection($server, $remote_host, $remote_port);
        }
        else {
            next unless exists $socket_map{$socket};
            my $remote = $socket_map{$socket};
            my $buffer;
            my $read = $socket->sysread($buffer, 4096);
            if ($read) {
                $remote->syswrite($buffer);
            }
            else {
                close_connection($socket);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And start it with

```
./tcp-proxy2.pl 8080 192.168.1.7:5555 &
```

Comment: sorry i can't install perl in my router, It lacks space

Answer (score 0):

Why not use iptable?
you can configure that every recieved packet on port 8080 will be transmitted to ip 192.168.1.7 on port 5555.

I have checked and openwrt **should** support iptable!
I don't know you specific router model but you can look http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/netfilter#
It will explain you how to work with Netfilters (the user-mode program is iptable).

iptable is very useful tool!

Comment: I did find very interesting things regarding iptables but i was not able to do port forwarding successfully. Please provide the command to do port forwarding otherwise i will end up in adding unusual rules to my firewall and lose it's connectivity.

Comment: I think what you are looking for can be found here: http://serverfault.com/questions/140622/how-can-i-port-forward-with-iptables

Comment: I am still facing the problem :-(

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo '<html>'
echo '<head>'
echo '<body>'
echo '<br><h3 align='left'>REMOTE MANAGEMENT</h3>'

if [ -z "$QUERY_STRING" ]; then
    ext_port=$(uci get firewall.remote_redirect.src_dport)
else
    intport=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*newid=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g" | sed "s/%40/@/g" | sed "s/%28/(/g" | sed "s/%29/)/g" | sed "s/%25/%/g" | sed "s/%2B/+/g" | sed "s/%23/#/g" | sed "s/%21/!/g" | sed "s/%24/$/g" | sed "s/%5E/^/g" | sed "s/%3D/=/g" | sed "s/%7E/~/g" | sed "s/%7C/|/g" | sed "s/%7B/{/g" | sed "s/%7D/}/g" | sed "s/%5B/[/g" | sed "s/%5D/]/g" | sed "s/%3A/:/g" | sed "s/%3B/;/g" | sed "s/%3F/?/g" | sed "s/%2C/,/g" | sed "s/%3C/</g" | sed "s/%3E/>/g"`
    extport=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*newpass=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g" | sed "s/%40/@/g" | sed "s/%28/(/g" | sed "s/%29/)/g" | sed "s/%25/%/g" | sed "s/%2B/+/g" | sed "s/%23/#/g" | sed "s/%21/!/g" | sed "s/%24/$/g" | sed "s/%5E/^/g" | sed "s/%3D/=/g" | sed "s/%7E/~/g" | sed "s/%7C/|/g" | sed "s/%7B/{/g" | sed "s/%7D/}/g" | sed "s/%5B/[/g" | sed "s/%5D/]/g" | sed "s/%3A/:/g" | sed "s/%3B/;/g" | sed "s/%3F/?/g" | sed "s/%2C/,/g" | sed "s/%3C/</g" | sed "s/%3E/>/g"`
fi

echo '
<style type="text/css">
    table 
    {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 60%;
    border:2px solid #999;
    }
    td
    {
    width: 50%;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 2px;
    }
    input
    {
    background-color:#e6f2ff;
    }
    #button
    {
    height: 30px;
    width: 70px;
    background: #27b3e4;
    border: 0 rgba(0,0,0,0);
    text-align: center;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 18px;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    }
    #button:hover
    {
    background: #0e99ca;
    }
</style>'
ext_port=$(uci get firewall.remote_redirect.src_dport)
echo "<form method=GET action=\"${SCRIPT}\" name="login">"\
'<table align="center">'\
'<tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;Web&nbsp;Management&nbsp;Port&nbsp;:</td><td><input type="number" name="newid" value="80"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;(Default&nbsp;Value&nbsp;is&nbsp;80)</td></tr>'\
'<tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;Redirect&nbsp;Port&nbsp;:</td><td><input type="number" name="newpass" value="'$ext_port'"/></td></tr>'\
'</table>'\
'<center><br><br><br><input id="button" type="submit" value="Save"/></center>'\
'</form>'
if [ "$REQUEST_METHOD" != "GET" ]; then
    echo "<hr>Script Error:"\
         "<br>Usage error, cannot complete request, REQUEST_METHOD!=GET."\
         "<br>Check your FORM declaration and be sure to use METHOD=\"GET\".            <hr>"
    exit 1
fi

if [ -z "$QUERY_STRING" ]; then
    exit 0
else
    intport=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*newid=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g" | sed "s/%40/@/g" | sed "s/%28/(/g" | sed "s/%29/)/g" | sed "s/%25/%/g" | sed "s/%2B/+/g" | sed "s/%23/#/g" | sed "s/%21/!/g" | sed "s/%24/$/g" | sed "s/%5E/^/g" | sed "s/%3D/=/g" | sed "s/%7E/~/g" | sed "s/%7C/|/g" | sed "s/%7B/{/g" | sed "s/%7D/}/g" | sed "s/%5B/[/g" | sed "s/%5D/]/g" | sed "s/%3A/:/g" | sed "s/%3B/;/g" | sed "s/%3F/?/g" | sed "s/%2C/,/g" | sed "s/%3C/</g" | sed "s/%3E/>/g"`
    extport=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*newpass=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g" | sed "s/%40/@/g" | sed "s/%28/(/g" | sed "s/%29/)/g" | sed "s/%25/%/g" | sed "s/%2B/+/g" | sed "s/%23/#/g" | sed "s/%21/!/g" | sed "s/%24/$/g" | sed "s/%5E/^/g" | sed "s/%3D/=/g" | sed "s/%7E/~/g" | sed "s/%7C/|/g" | sed "s/%7B/{/g" | sed "s/%7D/}/g" | sed "s/%5B/[/g" | sed "s/%5D/]/g" | sed "s/%3A/:/g" | sed "s/%3B/;/g" | sed "s/%3F/?/g" | sed "s/%2C/,/g" | sed "s/%3C/</g" | sed "s/%3E/>/g"`

t1=$(uci set firewall.remote_redirect=redirect)
t2=$(uci set firewall.remote_redirect.src=wan)
t3=$(uci set firewall.remote_redirect.src_dport=$extport)
t4=$(uci set firewall.remote_redirect.dest=lan)
t5=$(uci set firewall.remote_redirect.dest_port=$intport)
t6=$(uci set firewall.remote_redirect.target=DNAT)
t7=$(uci set firewall.remote_redirect.proto=tcp)
t8=$(uci commit firewall)
t9=$(/etc/init.d/firewall restart)

fi

echo '</head>'

echo '</body>'
echo '</html>'
exit 0
```

I think this will help you, I also developed this script for remote management in openwrt router and it worked for me.